# Create a list of 10 numbers that do not overlap each other and add them up

Tags: python, list, loops, sum

I'm supposed to write a code that asks users for 10 numbers, create a list with that and then sum them all up. I'm currently able to do that. However, I don't know how to check that the numbers do not overlap each other. If they do, the number is not supposed to be added onto the list.

So I am able to get the program to run such that it asks for a number for 10 times. However, after that, it appears to have a syntax error when producing the sum.

```
numberList = []

for i in range (0,10):
    number= int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    numberList.append(number)
    total = sum(numberList)
```

> total = sum(numberList)
>   TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Do you have a variable named `sum`?

Comment: sum variable might be overloaded. sum is buitlin function in python.you might have changed the definition of name sum by creating a variable with same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if condition with "not in", it will only add the new numbers in the list. I am not getting any error doing sum operation. May be there is sum indentation issue please check that.

```
numberList = []
for i in range (0,10):
    number= int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if number not in numberList:
        numberList.append(number)

print "List formed: %s" %numberList
total = sum(numberList)
print "Sum of all elements in list: %d" %total
```

Console:

```
Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: 2
Please enter a number: 3
Please enter a number: 4
Please enter a number: 5
Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: 2
Please enter a number: 3
Please enter a number: 4
Please enter a number: 5
List formed: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Sum of all elements in list: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicates from a python list can be done in a few different ways. The most common for lists that need to keep their order is to convert into an `OrderedDict` because `dictionary` keys must be unique it will not create additional keys for duplicate elements.

Because we are finding the sum of numbers, order does not matter so we can use a built-in method `set()` which converts any `iterable` in to a `set` (By nature, must have unique elements).

If you need it to be a list you can convert back to list afterwards:

```
numberList = list(set(numberList))
```

`reduce`, `map` and `filter` are some of the most important functions to learn in any programming language. For this use case the `reduce()` is perfect, it performs a rolling computation.

```
from functools import reduce
final_sum = reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), numberList)
```

Comment: Why would you not use the builtin `sum` instead of `reduce`? To make it worse you replace the `sum` function with an `int` - which seems to be the problem in the question.

Comment: The OP has overloaded the ```sum``` method, this is in fact the issue, not that the result is an ```int```. What are you talking about replacing the ```sum``` method with an ```int```? The ```sum``` function returns an ```int``` anyway.

Comment: After you use `sum = ...`, `sum` is rebound to an int. If you try to use `sum(numberList)` at that point, you'll get the error from the OP that the `int` is not callable

Comment: Sorry, your first message wasn't clear, you have an issue with the naming of the variable. I will change the post, all good :)